# convert .each (jquery) to Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert a function writing on jquery to javascript vanilla

i know that .each() is .forEach() on pure javascript but i dont understand what i'm missing with my code !

here the jquery code :

```
addClickItems: function(classe) {
    $(classe).each(function (index) {
        $(classe + ":eq(" + (index) + ")").click(function () {
            if (classe === ".droite") {

        });
    });
},
```

and here the javascript code :

```
clickImages : function (classe) {
    //classe = new Object(diaporama);
    Object.keys(classe).forEach(index => {
        classe[index].addEventListener("click", function () {

        });
    });
},
```

thanks for help !

Answer (score 4):

The **[`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** method enumerates all the individual DOM elements that are contained within the **[jQuery wrapped set of elements](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)** that you call it on:

```js
$("div").each(function(index, value){
  console.log(index, value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
<div id="three">three</div>
```

Your attempt at conversion goes to using `Object.keys(class).forEach`, where **[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** is not a set of elements, but keys/properties of an `Object`.

```js
var myObj = {
  key1: 10,
  key2: true,
  key3: "foo"
};

Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function(key, index){
  console.log(index, key, myObj[key]);
});
```

So, the two uses of `each` are not analogous.

If you do indeed have DOM elements to enumerate, you need to get them into a JavaScript array and then you can call **[`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** on that array.

**NOTE 1:** Most modern browsers allow you to call `.forEach` on node lists/HTML Collections directly, but for compatibility with those browsers that do not, you need to convert the node list/HTML Collection into an array to be sure that the code will work. This is shown below.

**NOTE 2:** Be mindful that the callback function you pass to `jQuery.forEach()` is, itself, passed two arguments: `index` and `value`, where for the vanilla JavaScript `Array.forEach()`, the callback is passed `value` and `index` (reversed order).

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("div");     // Get all the elements into a node list
var elArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);  // Convert node list to array

// Now, enumerate the array with .forEach()
elArray.forEach(function(value, index){
  console.log(index, value);
});
```

```html
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
<div id="three">three</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the original code `classe` appears to be a jQuery selector. You need to use `document.querySelectorAll()` to search for all the matching elements and iterate over that:

```
document.querySelectorAll(classe).forEach(elt => elt.addEventListener("click", function() { 
    ...
});
```